# Get value from input box added by script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

Better will be if you can see it. On my website [Loloid](http://www.loloid.thyon.cz)

There is input box, where user write his username. In menu is *region* and there user choose his region, where he plays. When he choose his region, in form is new hidden input with your region.

I have PHP file, where i save his username with **$_POST**, but it doesn't work for region. Here are my codes, I have no idea how to save my region with **$_POST**

```
//.Value are classes for regions   
    $('.Value').click(function(e){
        var value = $(e.target).text();
        $('.hiddenRegion').html(value);
    });
```

Here is HTML

```
<form method="post" action="lol.php" id="form">
    <ul>
        <li class="field">
            <input class="input" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Write a summoner name" name="summonerName" id="summonerName"/>
            <a id="formSubmit"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
            <input type="hidden" name="hiddenInput" class="hiddenRegion"></input>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

And PHP

```
$region = $_POST['hiddenInput'];
```

When i print **$region** with echo, it returns just blank string

Comment: Try to print_r($_POST) to see everything that is in POST. If there is nothing about region, inspect the form to see if `hiddenInput` is updated with the correct value in your form (in chrome inspector from example)

Comment: why are you putting the inner html of input to be the value?  If you want to store the value, you would want to do something like `$('.hiddenRegion').val(value);`   Also, where is `.Value` in your sample set?  I dont see anything there, which makes me wonder if that click function is actually being fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the input control values and not html.In-order to set or get input control  values one should use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

It should be  `$('.hiddenRegion').val(value);`

and not    `$('.hiddenRegion').html(value);`

And to get values

```
 $('.hiddenRegion').val()
```

Comment: How in the world i could be so blind. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Input tags never have `</input>` at the end, and you get and set its value in JavaScript using the `.value` property, or in JQuery the `.val` method.

So, this should fix your problem:

```
$('.Value').click(function(e){
    var value = $(e.target).text();
    $('.hiddenRegion').val(value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have another problem. The hidden input is generating a new input every single time you select a region prior to clicking search.

```
<li class="field">
   <input class="input" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Write a summoner name" name="summonerName" id="summonerName">
  <a onclick="$('#form').submit();"><i class="icon-search" style="top: -9%;"></i></a>
</li>

<input type="hidden" class="hiddenRegion" name="hiddenRegion" style="display: none;"></input>
<input type="hidden" class="hiddenRegion" name="hiddenRegion" style="display: none;"></input>
<input type="hidden" class="hiddenRegion" name="hiddenRegion" style="display: none;"></input>
```

Comment: You don't see full code. I have condition, where if .hiddenRegion.length > 1 so, it delete last child :)

Comment: Aha, ok, my bad :)

Comment: I know, it's bad solution, but best for my skills